# How to post JSON to a server using C#?

Tags: c#, json, post, httpwebrequest

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// create a request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url); request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";


// turn our request string into a byte stream
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

// this is important - make sure you specify type this way
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
request.UserAgent = currentUserAgent;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

// now send it
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

// grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result;
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}

return result;
```

When I'm running this, I'm always getting 500 internal server error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, make sure that the data you post is what the server expects.

Comment: actually, it looks like I was posting invalid data...

Comment: For ease of work you can add [json](http://www.json.net) library to your visual studio too

Comment: @Arsen - The server should not crash with malformed data. File a bug report.

Answer (score 494, accepted):

The way I do it and is working is:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                  "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I wrote a library to perform this task in a simpler way, it is here: https://github.com/ademargomes/JsonRequest

Comment: I think the json string line should be:
string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
              "\"password\":\"bla\"}";
It looks like you are missing a \

Comment: Always use "application/json" (unless for some other reason text/json is needed for example: http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/06/06/problems-with-internet-explorer-and-applicationjson/). Creding goes to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type.

Comment: I would've thought the streamWriter.Flush(); and streamWriter.Close(); is not necessary as you are inside a using block. At the end of the using block, stream writer will close anyway.

Comment: Hi @Albert it should as long as WebRequest is set to a https API/Site, please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389808/using-https-and-httpwebrequest

Comment: Short question: Why use `Close` when in `using` ?

Comment: Don't build JSON manually. It is easy to make mistakes that allow for JSON injection.

Comment: @FlorianWinter How to build the JSON instead?

Comment: @user3772108 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380064/2279059. Use a JSON library, such as Newtonsoft JSON.Net, and render the JSON string from an object, or use serialization. I understand that this was omitted here for simplicity (although the simplicity gain is minimal), but formatting structured data strings (JSON, XML, ...) is too dangerous to do it even in trivial scenarios and to encourage people to copy such code.

Comment: Using `async` methods where there are available is a good thing to do if you are in an async context. One other thing that I would want to point out is use of `var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");` why would you want to create a `WebRequest` instance and then parse it to `HttpWebRequest` while you have a method `CreateHttp`? Saves you from parsing the object. e.g `var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://url");`

Comment: I have followed the code,but it does not seem to post the json with the request. The method writes data to a table and the values are passed as null. Am I missing something? When I debug the string json does have a value.

Comment: Maybe more usings are needed? For the request: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't need it, but `request.GetRequestStream()` and `streamWriter` should each have their own using. Similar for the response: `request.GetResponse()`, `response.GetResponseStream()` and `StreamReader(responseStream)` each should have using IMO.

Comment: I've simplified the Json object: 

Person input = new PersonDto();

                    input.IdentificationNumber = identificationNumber;
                    input.FirstName = firstName;
                    input.LastName = lastName;

                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

Answer (score 174):

Ademar's solution can be improved by leveraging `JavaScriptSerializer`'s `Serialize` method to provide implicit conversion of the object to JSON.

Additionally, it is possible to leverage the `using` statement's default functionality in order to omit explicitly calling `Flush` and `Close`.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    user = "Foo",
                    password = "Baz"
                });

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the above code, am I missing something?

Comment: This uses the JavaScriptSerializer's Serialize method to create valid JSON instead of hand-crafting it.

Comment: See Jean F's answer below - should be a comment. Take care with the content type `application/json` is correct.

Comment: @SeanAnderson I keep having "Unable to connect to the remote server" Error.

Comment: I wonder why `JavaScriptSerializer` is not working on Unity3D. I used `using System.Web.Script.Serialization` directive, but namespace `Web` does not exists.

Comment: @LuzanBaral you just need an assembly: System.Web.Extensions

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` not works in dot net core. alternative is `using Newtonsoft.Json` and calling like: ` string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Username="Blahblah"});`

Answer (score 135):

The [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) type is a newer implementation than the `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest`. Both the `WebClient` and `WebRequest` have been marked as obsolete. [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated)

You can simply use the following lines.

```
string myJson = "{'Username': 'myusername','Password':'pass'}";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        "http://yourUrl", 
         new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

When you need your `HttpClient` more than once it's recommended to only create one instance and reuse it or use the new `HttpClientFactory`. [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

> For FTP, since HttpClient doesn't support it, we recommend using a third-party library.

@learn.microsoft.com [[3]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/http-client)

---

Since dotnet core 3.1 you can use the [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) from `System.Text.Json` to create your json string.

```
string myJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(credentialsObj);
```

Comment: A little note on HttpClient, the general consensus is that you should not dispose it. Even it implements IDisposable the object is Thread-Safe and meant to be reused.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Comment: @JeanF. Hey Thanks for the input. As I have allready noted you should only create one instance or use the `HttpClientFactory`. I did not read all answers in the linked issue but I think it needs updating as it doesn't mention the factory.

Answer (score 38):

Further to Sean's post, it isn't necessary to nest the using statements. By `using` the StreamWriter it will be flushed and closed at the end of the block so no need to explicitly call the `Flush()` and `Close()` methods:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    user = "Foo",
                    password = "Baz"
                });

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: now this answer and Sean Anderson's answer are exactly the same, as Sean has edited his post.

Comment: Hey this is so great.Thanks.But how are we going to pass data if we have child nodes on our json?

Comment: The serializer can handle child nodes in json - you just have to provide it a valid json object.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to call is asynchronously then use

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.maplegraphservices.com/tokkri/webservices/updateProfile.php?oldEmailID=" + App.currentUser.email) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/json";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


        // Create the post data
        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(edit).ToString();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        //Start the web request
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponceStreamCallback), request);
    }

    void GetResponceStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            stat.Text = result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution Vivek. In our scenario we tried another solution in this post, and wound up seeing System.Threading exceptions in our application, due to what I assume were synchronous posts blocking threads. Your code solved our problem.

Comment: Note that you probably don't have to convert to bytes. You should be able to do `postStream.Write(postData);` - and depending on the API, might have to use a `request.ContentType = "application/json";` instead of `text/json`.

Answer (score 14):

I recently came up with a much simpler way to post a JSON, with the additional step of converting from a model in my app. Note that you have to make the model `[JsonObject]` for your controller to get the values and do the conversion.

**Request:**

```
 var model = new MyModel(); 

 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
     var uri = new Uri("XXXXXXXXX"); 
     var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
     var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     var response = await client.PutAsync(uri,stringContent).Result;
     // ...
  }
```

**Model:**

```
[JsonObject]
[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
    public Decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

**Server side:**

```
[HttpPut]     
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutApi([FromBody]MyModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Take care of the Content-Type you are using :

```
application/json
```

Sources :

[RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

[Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Answer (score 11):

Up to .Net 4.5.1 [this option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx) can work:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var foo = new User
    {
        user = "Foo",
        password = "Baz"
    }

    await client.PostAsJsonAsync("users/add", foo);
}
```

Comment: This option is no longer available since .Net 4.5.2. see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40525794/2161568

Comment: Thats not a good reason to downvote this answer since not everyone uses the latest versions of .net and therefore this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 9):

**WARNING! I have a very strong view on this subject.**

**.NET’s existing web clients are not developer friendly!** [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest) & [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) are prime examples of "how to frustrate a developer". They are verbose & complicated to work with; when all you want to do is a simple Post request in C#. [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) goes some way in addressing these issues, but it still falls short. On top of that Microsoft’s documentation is bad … really bad; unless you want to sift through pages and pages of technical blurb.

**Open-source to the rescue.** There are three excellent open-source, free NuGet libraries as alternatives. Thank goodness! These are all well supported, documented and yes, easy - correction…super easy - to work with.

- [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) - fast, light and resilient.
- [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) - simple REST and HTTP API Client
- [Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl)- a fluent, portable, testable HTTP client library

There is not much between them, but I would give ServiceStack.Text the slight edge …

- *Github stars* are roughly the same.
- *Open Issues & importantly how quickly any issues closed down?* ServiceStack takes the award here for the fastest issue resolution & no open issues.
- *Documentation?* All have great documentation; however, ServiceStack takes it to the next level & is known for its ‘Golden standard’ for documentation.

**Ok - so what does a Post Request in JSON look like within ServiceStack.Text?**

```
var response = "http://example.org/login"
    .PostJsonToUrl(new Login { Username="admin", Password="mypassword" });
```

That is one line of code. Concise & easy! Compare the above to .NET’s Http libraries.

Comment: It is a crime that it is as hard as it is to do simple REST calls in .net. What takes me a short time in Javascript took a large chunk of the day to figure out in c# and there were like a dozen different opinions on the right way and none of them worked for me? RestSharp finally saved the day - but I had to get past their incomplete docs.

Answer (score 4):

Some different and clean way to achieve this is by using HttpClient like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostResult(string url, ResultObject resultObject)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, resultObject);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex
        }
        return response;
     }
}
```

Comment: Helpful, however `PostAsJsonAsync` is no longer available since .NET 4.5.2. Use `PostAsync` instead. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594919/4461141)

Comment: HttpClient generally shouldn't be used in a `using` statement like this

Comment: I think it implements `IDisposable` interface for a reason

Comment: This works in .net core 2.1, and is a very clean option. If you inject your httpClient, this becomes a 1 line json Post.

Answer (score 4):

I finally invoked in sync mode by including the *.Result*

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
       response = client.PostAsync(
        "http://localhost:8000/....",
         new StringContent(myJson,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");              
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOK");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this to be the friendliest and most concise way to post an read JSON data:

```
var url = @"http://www.myapi.com/";
var request = new Request { Greeting = "Hello world!" };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Request>(request);
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var jsonResponse = client.UploadString(url, json);
    var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(jsonResponse);
}
```

I'm using Microsoft's `System.Text.Json` for serializing and deserializing JSON. See [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it

```
//URL
var url = "http://www.myapi.com/";

//Request
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

//Headers
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

//Payload
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        Text = "Hello world"
    });
request.Content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//Send
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

//Handle response
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dot net core solution

first using `Newtonsoft.Json` then write a method like this:

```cs
    public static string? LoginToken()
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
           //  write your json content here
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                userName = ApiOptions.Username,
                password = ApiOptions.Password
            }
            );


            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }

    }
```

This method return `string`. if you want to deserialize the `string` result to `JSON`, simply add this line at the end of the method:

```
var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();               
var json_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginTokenResponse>(result); // + add this code
```

Which `LoginTokenResponse` is the custom class you want to Deserialize the string result

Answer (score -1):

`var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);`

`byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);`

Use ASCII instead of UFT8

Comment: sounds like a pretty bad idea, am i missing something?

Comment: JSON can contain UTF8 characters, this seems like a terrible idea.