# How to deserialize json to multiple types dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have a json string like below :

{ 
"error" : "xxxx" , 
"data" : int type **or** {...other complex json object} 
}

I don't know when return int or other json string from data field , and how to deserialize this ?

when type of data is object or dynamic , the real deserialized type of data is int or Dictionary using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(string json).

the real deserialized type of data is Int64 or JContainer when using Json.Net.

is there a elegance way to solve this ? I don't think reflection is a good way.

Comment: have a look at this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-the-server/10027534#10027534


Here is the library I mention in this post, I wrote it to help me deserialize/serialize json requests/responses.

https://github.com/ademargomes/JsonRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create object-wrapper and put data type identificator to the first field of this wrapper.