# HttpClient not supporting PostAsJsonAsync method C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call a web API from my web application. I am using .Net 4.5 and while writing the code I am getting the error `HttpClient` does not contain a definition `PostAsJsonAsync` method.

Below is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51093/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
   new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var user = new Users();
user.AgentCode = 100;
user.Remarks = "Test";
user.CollectionDate = System.DateTime.Today;
user.RemittanceDate = System.DateTime.Today;
user.TotalAmount = 1000;
user.OrgBranchID = 101;

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/AgentCollection", user).Result;
```

and I am getting the error message:

> Error:  'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' does not contain a definition for
>   'PostAsJsonAsync' and No extension method 'PostAsJsonAsync' accepting a first argument of
>   type     'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please have a look  and advice me.

Comment: The best option is to add 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' .Nuget package. That's it!

Answer (score 550, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a reference to

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
```

This can be found in the extensions assemblies area.

A good way of achieving this is by adding the [NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) to your project.

Comment: Now  i am getting an error :" Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. "

Comment: Go into NuGet and look up Json.NET under online packages, or you can download from here if you aren't using NuGet get it from here http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: Here is the console command if anyone is looking http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting

Comment: Found I had to add the NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" to ensure the version of the formatting dll worked with the .NET framework version of "System.Net.Http" in my project.

Comment: Why does referencing a standard system assembly require me to download open source stuff from random locations on the Internet in order to get it to function? Why does this even compile if it cannot resolve its dependencies? This irks me to no end!

Comment: @Neutrino Would you rather write the code yourself? You should be thankful that the folks at Microsoft and elsewhere have written code you can use for free

Comment: is there a way to use this method from UWP app?

Comment: PM> Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension

Comment: how will this be added in .net4

Comment: After I added System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension from NuGet, HttpClient was thrown an error. Now I am finding the root cause. Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: What the answer should *actually say*. *Nuget > Install System.Net.Http* then install *System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension*

Comment: @Yusha I needed to add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension, then it compiled.

Comment: 2020 answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64015973/578552

Answer (score 241):

`PostAsJsonAsync` is no longer in the `System.Net.Http.dll` (.NET 4.5.2). You can add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`, but this actually belongs to an older version. I ran into problems with this on our TeamCity build server, these two wouldn't cooperate together.

Alternatively, you can replace `PostAsJsonAsync`with a `PostAsync` call, which is just part of new dll. 
Replace

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/AgentCollection", user).Result;
```

With:

```
var response = client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", new StringContent(
   new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Note that `JavaScriptSerializer` is in the namespace: `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

You will have to add an assembly reference in your csproj: `System.Web.Extensions.dll`

See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836

Comment: This should be the answer. The best way to do something is the correct way of it

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Do not try adding NuGet packages or dlls.

Comment: Totally the best answer. Selected answer is not a best practice _at all_, in fact Microsoft recommends not to reference DLLs

Comment: Off topic, but I want to mention it anyways: Use `await FooAsync()` instead of `FooAsync().Result`. The latter one can deadlock. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17248680/2272514 and its accepted answer. There are also good links about details.

Comment: To use a type instead of "application/json" you could use MediaTypeNames.Application.Json
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application.json?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: This helped me and is obviously preferable to installing a library via nuget. Thank you.

Comment: Worked a charm - I successfully used JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user) in place of your serialiser.

Comment: This is the second time I've forgotten this answer. PostAsJsonAsync will mysteriously exclude properties from the object you're posting when serializing etc. and no amount of attribute changes etc. will fix it. You MUST serialize yourself and you MUST use the "raw" PostAsync.

Comment: Great - I used this for the general idea when debugging some json from .net core 2.2. From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/29843542/292060 it shows using existing Newtonsoft library to serialize (even though the post is about how that's being removed from core 3.0)

Answer (score 170):

The missing reference is the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`.  But the better solution is to add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` to ensure the version of the formatting dll worked with the .NET framework version of `System.Net.Http` in my project.

Comment: @Yuval - I realize now that the "solution" I suggested sounded like a comment.  It turns out that Andreo authored the NuGet package I suggested.

Comment: This was the answer to me! (to my question)

Answer (score 41):

As already debatted, this method  isn't available anymore since .NET 4.5.2. To expand on [Jeroen K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594919/2441442) you can make an extension method:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<TModel>(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, TModel model)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(model);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, stringContent);
}
```

Now you are able to call `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/AgentCollection", user)`.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue too on a project I'd just checked out from source control.

The symptom was the error described above and a yellow warning triangle on a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

To fix this, I removed the broken reference and then used NuGet to install the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`.

Comment: It works! To install by Nuget Console enter `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client `

Answer (score 5):

I know this reply is too late, I had the same issue and i was adding the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` Nuget, after checking here and there I found that the Nuget is added but the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` was not added to the references, I just reinstalled the Nuget

Answer (score 5):

Try to install in your project the NuGet Package:  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, it is apocalyptical 2020 now, and you can find these methods in NuGet package `System.Net.Http.Json`. But beware that it uses `System.Text.Json` internally.

And if you really need to find out which API resides where, just use https://apisof.net/

Comment: Works for me for .net framework and netcore3.1 (which uses netstandard2.0 in this library)

Answer (score 5):

If you are already using Newtonsoft.Json try this:

```
  // Alternative using WebApi.Client 5.2.7
  ////var response = await Client.PutAsJsonAsync(
  ////    "api/AgentCollection", user
  ////    requestListDto)

  var response = await Client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", new StringContent(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Performance are better than JavaScriptSerializer. Take a look here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing this amount of code to make a simple call, you could use one of the wrappers available over the internet.

I've written one called WebApiClient, available at NuGet... check it out!

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRestService.WebApiClient/

Comment: [@Andreo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3738778/andreo-romera) The link (http://webapiclient.azurewebsites.net) is now broken as on 30-Nov-2017.  
NuGet working link is https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRestService.WebApiClient/

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft has ended my azure subscription and the url is no longer valid :(

Comment: Actually, this is a really good demonstration of why using "one of the wrappers available over the internet" might not be a good idea.  Every external dependency that a project has is one more thing that can go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing around in Blazor and get the error, you need to add the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594919/48729) with the tips in comments:

```
var content = new StringContent(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), 
    Encoding.UTF8, 
    MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

var response = await client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", content);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I found the solution after a lot of try which is replacing

```
HttpClient
```

with

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blazor components and getting this error that means your component is not able to find the http client.
use this line on top on your blazor component.

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

Make sure you have this line in your Program or startup file

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers here talking about using Newtonsoft.Json, I created a helper class for this:

```
public class JsonContent : StringContent
{
    public JsonContent(object model) 
        : base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    {
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
using (var content = new JsonContent(user))
{
    var response = client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", content).Result;
}
```