# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync incompatible with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

Something I have just picked up in my winforms app

My app does an http call to a web Api service as follows

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://Myserver/MyApp");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response =  _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Addin", newObject).Result;
```

Nothing fancy, but as soon as you install Newtonsoft.Json  (V6.0.3) via nuget

suddenly I get a stackOverflow error on the HttpResponseMessage line of code.
remove Newtonsoft, and problem is solved.

The problem is I was to use the library to serialize/deserialize data elsewhere in my form

My workaround was to use a different library, I am just using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; but this is still really weird, no?

I should also add that this is dotnet v4.0  (not 4.5), and my app is a VSTO COM object running in MsWord as an Add On

I suspect a bug maybe in Newtonsoft

Comment: What's on the stack in case of that stack overflow? Enable external code.

Comment: Enable external code? U mean I should grab the newtonsoft source and allow debugging in outside class libraries? Ill hunt down the source for that version now

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I meant enable "Show External Code". That a menu option in the stack trace window.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try get that. problem is that it doesn't always give me the debug breakpoint. this is a VSTO ms word addin, and sometime ms word just crokes completely

Comment: @Crudler I'm guessing you never figured this out?  I'm getting the same error and am hoping there's a solution other than not including Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: No.  I completely removed newtonsoft from my project and used microsofts native json serialisation library

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is the `PostAsJsonAsync` method, you are better off writing your own extension method.

I recommend removing the reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` (when I use PostAsJsonAsync from this package, it complains that it can't find an older version of Newtonsoft.Json, but the thing is that I need the latest version.  my project targets .net framework 4.7.2) anyhow...

Here is code that you can copy and paste.

I've used the fully qualified names so you don't have to worry about adding `using` statements.

I'm also using the Newtonsoft.Json library to serialize the object.

```
public static class HttpClientExt
{
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUrl, T theObj)
    {
        var stringContent = new StringContent(
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObj),
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, stringContent);
    }
}
```

Modified from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40525794/2205372

Comment: Why don't you use `await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(theObj)`?

Answer (score 3):

Install the "microsoft asp.net web api 2.2 client libraries" from nuget and don't refer the system.net.http.dll and system.net.http.formatting.dll manually. If you install this package then will install the correct json.net as well

Answer (score -1):

I received the error after updating to a newer version of the Newtonsoft.Json package.

Uninstalling the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nugget package and reinstalling it after upgrading to the newer Newtonsoft.Json package resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work (.net framework 4.7.2)