# JSON serialization/deserialization in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Since there is no `JavaScriptSerializer`, what native implementation can be used to handle this?

I noticed `JsonResult` and I can format data to JSON with this, but how do I deserialize?

Or maybe I am missing some dependencies in `project.json`?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json`, it's a dependency of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding` which is a dependency of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. So, you don't need to add a dependency in your project.json.

```
#using Newtonsoft.Json
....
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Note, using a WebAPI controller you don't need to deal with JSON.

#### UPDATE ASP.Net Core 3.0

[Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) has been removed from the ASP.NET Core 3.0 shared framework.

You can use the new JSON serializer layers on top of the high-performance `Utf8JsonReader` and `Utf8JsonWriter`. It deserializes objects from JSON and serializes objects to JSON. Memory allocations are kept minimal and includes support for reading and writing JSON with Stream asynchronously.

To get started, use the `JsonSerializer` class in the `System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespace. See the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to.md) for information and samples.

To use Json.NET in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project:

- Add a package reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson)
- Update ConfigureServices to call AddNewtonsoftJson().

```cs
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Read [Json.NET support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support) in [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 Preview 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for more information.

Comment: Now AspNetCore.Mcv has no dependencies on Newtonsoft.JSON . Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json assembly used for serialization.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij, wrong, : `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json` has a dependency to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` which has a dependency to `Newtonsoft.Json` 9.0.1 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/

Comment: You can also use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json) to deserialize to an specific class.

Answer (score 47):

.net core

`using System.Text.Json;`

###To serialize

```
var jsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyObject)
```

###Deserialize

```
var weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonStr);
```

For more information about excluding properties and nulls check out
[This Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-read-json-into-net-objects-deserialize)

Comment: do you know how to deserialize json to dynamic type?

Comment: Be aware that System.Text.Json is a "lossy" serializer and will not include properties that are on base classes.