# Docker run volume parameter Specify --help for a list of available options and commands

Tags: docker, .net-core

.Net core console app reads config file on main like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

     var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .AddJsonFile("//home/processorconfig/appsettings.json");

     var configuration = configBuilder.Build();
     ...
}
```

When I run docker image with -v parameter

```
docker run -v C:\Configs\:/home/processorconfig/ -it  858a565b2069
```

output is:

> Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.

When I change just a letter in volume parameter it runs container but app gets exception

```
docker run -v C:\Configs\:/home/processorconfg/ -it  858a565b2069
```

Output:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The
>   configuration file 'processorconfig/appsettings.json' was not found
>   and is not optional. The physical path is
>   '/home/processorconfig/appsettings.json'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean
>   reload)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1
>   providers)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()

When I change console app AddJsonFile path to another, and then add volume to the path on run, I got same output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Same result with `--mount` parameter

Update: Found a clue that when I delete appsetings.json in C:\Configs it runs container and get exception message.

Comment: You wrote that you change a letter in the volume parameter but pasted the same line. Either way, seems like your missing an 'i' in your command line argument `/home/processorconfg`

Comment: You re right, i mispasted command to queson. I have updated

Comment: That "change one letter and it almost works" thing smells a lot like file access conflict. Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Some of the examples under docker for windows and [sharing drives](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives) seems to substitute forward slashes, for back slashes. Maybe that'll be of use for Windows paths for the --mount parameter too.

Comment: @Eran question updated

Comment: It's not the Dockerfile, so maybe the `ConfigurationBuilder` API is keeping the file exclusively open. Perhaps if you used the [`reloadOnChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_JsonConfigurationExtensions_AddJsonFile_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) flag it would work? Or use a custom file provider?

Comment: I got same error in every path or without path when `realoadOnChange = true`

Comment: Thanks @Eran, using custom profiler solved my problem.

Comment: @hkutluay thanks for posting the solution. Probably a typo there and should be provider instead of profiler, no?

Comment: @Eran, yes you are right. Answer updated, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is possibly related with file system watch does not work with mounted volumes on Docker. (Details on [aspnet GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/908) and [Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038)).

Reading file with `File.ReadAllText` command and pass string to [InMemoryFileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405277/840566) saved my day.

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("//home/processorconfig/appsettings.json");
var memoryFileProvider = new InMemoryFileProvider(jsonString);
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(memoryFileProvider, "appsettings.json", false, false)
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this from the directory that you want to map to the container:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/home/processorconfig/ -it  858a565b2069
```

This will get the path of your current directory (print working directory).

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: create ${PWD}: "${PWD}" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Are you using Power Shell or  Git Bash ?

Comment: Same result that in question on PowerShell (Specify --help for a list of..  )

Comment: Sorry. I made a typo. Is $(pwd):/home/processorconfig and not ${PWD}. pwd with parentheses. I will edit that.

Comment: Now error is :  invalid reference format. I think that ${PWD} command was correct syntax. Error possibly related with reading file, please find update on question.

Comment: I think you are missing the workdir in your dockerfile. WORKDIR /Processor. This will set the context where you are running your application from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187875/discussion-between-carlos-jafet-neto-and-hkutluay).

Answer (score 0):

The colon in the path may be problematic. I'm not on a windows machine so can't validate. Try using the [`--mount`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) syntax:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=C:\Configs\,target=/home/processorconfig/ -it  858a565b2069
```

Comment: same result, screenshot added to question