# Azure Functions, how to have multiple .json config files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0

So I have written an azure function that works locally just fine. I believe this is down to having the `local.setting.json` file. But when I publish it to azure the function does not work as it can't find the settings values that I had defined. Coming from a web app and console driven approach, we would have different config files that would be associated with each environment. How can I get this to work so I can have multiple `settings.json` files, e.g. one for dev, stag and prod environments? The end result is to get this deployed with octopus deploy, but at this point, if I cant even get it working with a publish then there is no chance of doing this.

I'm rather confused why this information is not easily available, as would presume it is a common thing to do?

Comment: One proper way is to add them as ARM template during the deployment of your app so that they appear in your `Function App -> configuration -> Application Settings`. As you have different templates per environment you can vary the variables per template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I have it working now :) Because we use octopus deploy we don't want multiple config files so we just have the one **appsettings.Release.json** file which gets the values substituted base on the environment being deployed too.

Below is the main function code.

```
public static class Function
    {
        // Format in a CRON Expression e.g. {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer
        // [TimerTrigger("0 59 23 * * *") = 11:59pm
        [FunctionName("Function")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 59 23 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {

            // If running in debug then we dont want to load the appsettings.json file, this has its variables substituted in octopus
            // Running locally will use the local.settings.json file instead
#if DEBUG
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
#else
            IConfiguration config = Utils.GetSettingsFromReleaseFile();
#endif

            // Initialise dependency injections
            var serviceProvider = Bootstrap.ConfigureServices(log4Net, config);

            var retryCount = Convert.ToInt32(config["RetryCount"]);

            int count = 0;
            while (count < retryCount)
            {
                count++;
                try
                {
                    var business = serviceProvider.GetService<IBusiness>();
                    business.UpdateStatusAndLiability();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Log your error
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

The **Utils.cs** file looks as follows

```
public static class Utils
    {

        public static string LoadSettingsFromFile(string environmentName)
        {
            var executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            // We need to go back up one level as the appseetings.Release.json file is not put in the bin directory
            var actualPathToConfig = Path.Combine(executableLocation, $"..\\appsettings.{environmentName}.json");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(actualPathToConfig))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        public static IConfiguration GetSettingsFromReleaseFile()
        {
            var json = Utils.LoadSettingsFromFile("Release");
            var memoryFileProvider = new InMemoryFileProvider(json);

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(memoryFileProvider, "appsettings.json", false, false)
                .Build();
            return config;
        }

    }
```

The **appsettings.Release.json** is set as **Content** and **Copy Always** in visual studio. It looks like this

```
{
  "RetryCount": "#{WagonStatusAndLiabilityRetryCount}",
  "RetryWaitInSeconds": "#{WagonStatusAndLiabilityRetryWaitInSeconds}",
  "DefaultConnection": "#{YourConnectionString}"
}
```

Actually I believe you could have an appsettings.config file there already and skip the appsettings.Release.json file, but this is working and you can do what you want with it now.

Comment: I don't see where you are getting this class:InMemoryFileProvider from.

Comment: I imagine its something like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405277/277067, I don't have the code available. Also googling "ConfigurationBuilder addjsonfile in memory" returns the same page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807836/loading-startup-configuration-from-json-located-in-memory

Comment: Even with this I am having a hard time getting my individual projects to load the json file I added to the project. I have a settings file that I want the DB project to load it up. dbAppsettings is the file I want to have it load up when I am running the API and have a settings file that is for parsing the Web API objects.

Answer (score 4):

I would love to see functions support environment specific settings in the same way as asp.net core or console apps. In the meantime I am using below code, which is somewhat hacky (see comments).

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Get the path to the folder that has appsettings.json and other files.
        // Note that there is a better way to get this path: ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory when running inside a function. But we don't have access to the ExecutionContext here.
        // Functions team should improve this in future. It will hopefully expose FunctionAppDirectory through some other way or env variable.
        string basePath = IsDevelopmentEnvironment() ?
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot") :
            $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")}\\site\\wwwroot";

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)  // common settings go here.
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)  // environment specific settings go here
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)  // secrets go here. This file is excluded from source control.
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
    }

    public bool IsDevelopmentEnvironment()
    {
        return "Development".Equals(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is similar to what I am doing, but using octopus deploy I will have one json file that will hopefully get the config values injected into, so will put the relevant values for dev, stag and prod. The above approach is what I have, but wanted to make it more compatible with our octopus deploy release.

Comment: Building upon this, you can access the `ExecutionContextOptions` like the following: `builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;`

Answer (score 1):

This doc has the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) about `local.settings.json`:

> By default, these settings are not migrated automatically when the
>   project is published to Azure.

One way is using `--publish-local-settings`:

> Publish settings in local.settings.json to Azure, prompting to
>   overwrite if the setting already exists.

Another way is to use the `Manage Application Settings`, the **Remote**  is the current setting in the function app in Azure. Or choose Add setting to create a new app setting. For details you could refer to this doc:[Function app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings).

[image]

Comment: Yes may have something working just need to confirm, Not to keen on publishing a local settings file. also application settings don't seem to give me enough options for all the environments. Ill post my solution soon, cheers

Comment: @Andrew, if you use Azure Functions Core Tools, you could use --publish-local-settings make sure these settings are added to the function app in Azure. But if not, yes you have to add it manually.