# Production Configuration for Azure Function App

Tags: configuration, azure-functions

In aspnetcore apps we include a appsettings.{environment}.json for each configuration / environment.

Looking at deploying our first function apps - I have a testing and production stage set-up for our release pipeline.

How do I go about setting the environment and corresponding configuration file to use for a function app?  Is it the same environment variable without the full IHostingEnvironment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-built support for appsettings.json files is unfortunately not supported in Azure functions (yet). There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4761) that tracks this.

There are few ways to do things at present. I posted a solution in response to a similar question earlier:
[Azure Functions, how to have multiple .json config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457072/azure-functions-how-to-have-multiple-json-config-files/56475257#56475257)

There is also a similar solution described at github:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4464#issuecomment-494367524

Comment: I used the second link.  Not the greatest - but it will work.

Comment: I used the second link.  Not the greatest - but it will work.