# How to read custom configuration settings?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

While deploying azure functions in app service, other than adding the custom configuration settings and connection strings at the azure portal, is there a way to add these entries in an app settings file deployed with the runtime dlls and read it from there?

Trying to avoid manually maintaining these entries at the portal level for each environment.

Comment: What do you use for build & release management? If you're using Azure DevOps you could use the Azure Function App task and specify the settings in there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-built support for appsettings.json files is unfortunately not supported in Azure functions (yet). There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4761) that tracks this.

There are few ways to achieve this at present. Look at this answer at stackoveflow:
[Azure Functions, how to have multiple .json config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457072/azure-functions-how-to-have-multiple-json-config-files/56475257#56475257)

There is also a similar solution described at github:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4464#issuecomment-494367524

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer **`No`**,

Everyone should use **`local.settings.json`** since the **`appsettings.json`** was renamed to local.settings.json.

Find the reference **[`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/122)**