# Cannot create convert to JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc

I want a make some chart, based on class Result (i use CodeFirst)

I have class `Results.cs`

```
namespace PersonalArea.DAL.Models
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string PatientId { get; set; }

        public string GameName { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateExit { get; set; }

        public string DifficultLevel { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And method in controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            List<IGrouping<string, Result>> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList();
            ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
            return View(results);
        }
```

My ViewModel

```
using PersonalArea.DAL.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PersonalArea.WebUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ResultChartModel
    {
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Result>> Results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my View.cshtml

```
window.onload = function ()
        {
            var test = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.test));
            var datapoints = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
            {
                var str_array = test[i].Score;

                for (var j = 0; j < str_array.length; j++)
                {
                    datapoints.push({ y: str_array[j], x: str_array[j], label: test[i].GameName });
                }
            }
```

And i have a error

> JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type
>   'PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result'. Path '[0][0].patient.results'.

On

```
ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

Please, help my resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

In your Model change like:

```
   public class ResultChartModel
    {
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

In your controller :

replace

```
    List<IGrouping<string, Result>> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList();
    ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

by

```
    List<Result> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).OrderBy(z => z.GameName).ThenBy(z => z.DateExit).ToList();
  ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

Then Your View :

Change

```
var test = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.test);
```

To

```
var test = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.Test));
```

JS:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {  

        datapoints.push({ y: test[i].Score x: test[i].DateExit, label: test[i].GameName });

 }
```

Hopefully it's help you.

Comment: He don't understand this new JavaScriptSerializer()

Comment: How i make resolve it?

Comment: @TravisBincle .Sorry for my grate mistake. It's ASP.NET MVC not ASP.NET CORE. so I Update my answer. and use `Newtonsoft.Json`.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841503/json-serialization-deserialization-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks, error is gone, but my page is empty. Why it can be? I updated my view page, maybe there problem?

Comment: Oh, that my fail, i put extra parenthesis, thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, wait, i have a question - chart show only first data, how can show all data?

Comment: check your `List<Result>`. is it only one item or not? if yes. then think about your Group By statement according your business.

Comment: No, there is a three and many data. So, GroupBy i used, because want  to devide scores to GameName. In a table i can do it, but in chart i can show only last of first data. How i can to avoid this?

Comment: If you want to take last item then `results.OrderByDescending(a => a.XXX).Take(1).` OR `results.OrderByDescending(a => a.XXX).FirstOrDefault().`

Comment: No, no, i need take all items, not last or first

Comment: Please,help my choose all items of this List.

Comment: Is `datapoints` has all item of `results` item?

Comment: Table Results have 3 or more items. For example: GameName "Stars" have Scores 10, 3, 11, 15. GameName "Cars" have Scores 5, 9. But on Chart i can see only: GameName "Stars" -15 scores and GameName "Cars" - 9 scores. How i can show in graph ALL scores. It is possible?

Comment: all scores are coma separated or list item?

Comment: list item. But Chart show only last item

Comment: @TravisBincle I update my answer. Please inform your status.

Comment: Ok, i inform you when i get to the computer and change my code!

Comment: i change my code on yours, but counts on chart is gone. What me doing? I updated my code, when you can see my changed (x and y i I decided designated how score)

Comment: Let me show my database, what you seen how i placed my scores http://oi64.tinypic.com/qo926x.jpg

Comment: @TravisBincle you don't need grouping any more. I update my full answer.

Comment: Thanks you, i checked tommorrow, and i inform my status. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. My system have a error "JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result'. Path '[0].Patient.Results'." What me doing?

Comment: Okey, i fixed this problem. Thank you very much!