# C# Difference between Serializable Attribute and Serializing?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, .net-core

Why is there a Serializable attribute `[Serializable]`, when one can just serialize as below in Net Core?

```
var test= JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyObject)
```

What is the difference between these two?

**Resources:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877839/12425844

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29843542/12425844

Comment: Calling .serialize actually serialises the object. Adding the serializable attribute allows you to be selective about which properties are serialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most JSON and XML formatter doesn't required `[Serializable]` attribute when serializing an object. But some required it, like when you using `BinaryFormatter` when serializing an object.

Article, [Do we really need SerializableAttribute?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/379005/373618)