# Send a POST request to an API with IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I need to consume an API HTTPPost from my WPF. I made this command:

```cs
public async override void Execute(object? parameter)
{
    string localHost = "https://localhost:7235/api/SalePerson/InsertSalePerson";
    var person = new DistrictAndSalePerson { name = _showDistrictViewModel.SalepersonToAdd, districtname = _showDistrictViewModel.SelectedDistrictTest };

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var todoItemJson = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(person),
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json");
    using var httpResponse =
        await httpClient.PostAsync(localHost, todoItemJson);

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(localHost, todoItemJson);
    var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The API is:

```cs
[HttpPost("InsertSalePerson")]
[ProducesResponseType(  StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSalePerson(
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string name,
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string districtname)
{
    try
    {
        await _districtRepo.InsertSalePerson(name, districtname);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it always returns a validation error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "name": ["The name field is required."],
        "districtname": ["The districtname field is required."]
    },
    "traceId": "00-d8380633c81cdd4c0a7560cceff50c7a-0482c70fcbcf252f-00"
}
```

I know it is semantics but I cannot see it. I work in .Net Core 8. I would like to understand the error, I already tried to make it work with `HttpClient` and other methods on this site.
Could you please help?

Comment: Create a model for both parameters `name` and `districtname` for your `InsertSalePerson` API . And change the method signature as `public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSalePerson([FromBody] InsertSalePersonModel model)`

Comment: @YongShun Great It works. But now I do not have the 2 required textboxes for district and name in my api. Do you  Do you know a way I can send the PostAsync while keeping  the textboxes  [Required(All....

Answer (score 1):

With your current code:

```cs
[HttpPost("InsertSalePerson")]
[ProducesResponseType(  StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSalePerson(
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string name,
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string districtname)
{
    ...
}
```

the action expects to receive both `name` and `districtname` as query string parameters, but you are posting the JSON object as a request body.

You should create a model class by adding the parameters

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class InsertSalePerson
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Districtname { get; set; }
}
```

And modify the action signature with [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#frombody-attribute) attribute.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSalePerson([FromBody] InsertSalePersonModel model)
{

    ...

    await _districtRepo.InsertSalePerson(model.Name, model.Districtname);

    ....
}
```

Alternatively, you can post the JSON body via `PostAsJsonAsync`.

For .NET Framework: [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158378/httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp)
For .NET 8: [System.Net.Http.Json (namespace)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-8.0)

```cs
using var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(localHost, person);
```

Comment: It works, great, thank you. I will miss those textboxes in the API though.

Comment: You are welcome. The textbox you mentioned `[...]` is called [`Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/attribute-tutorial).