# Calling REST service from C# code

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am using the following code to call a REST service using C#

```
 string PostData= @"{""name"":""TestName""}";

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://something.com:1234/content/abc.v1.json");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        try
        {  // Gets exception
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

             ....
             }
        }
```

And I am getting an exception "400 bad request" on the line calling `GetResponse()`. The documentation of the service says the status code 400 means a required argument is missing. But as you can see the argument `name` (which is the only required argument ) is supplied with the request.

I tried to call the service with CURL and it successfully got executed.

> curl -v -b cookie.txt -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
>   "{\"name\": \"TestName\"}"
>   http://something.com:1234/content/abc.v1.json

So I assume there is something wrong with my C# code which doesn't seem to be passing the parameters. Any idea?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant part of the documentation:

**Method**

POST

**Headers**

**Content-Type:**   application/json

**Body**

The request body is made up of JSON containing the following properties:

**Name**    : name       **Required**   : yes   **Type**: string

**Response
Status codes**

201 Created Success

400 Bad Request A required property is missing in the request body.

Comment: Consider using RestSharp; it's a fantastic interface for RESTful services.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Thankz but 3rd party services are not allowed

Comment: Third party services? Or do you mean third party libraries? And what is the **actual** constraint there?

Comment: I mean third party libraries

Comment: Have you tried sending the data as a string instead of encoded bytes? The `StreamWriter` class would allow that. See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027534/1346943)

Comment: @ledbutter Tried that. same result :(

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I tried with RestSharp too, but the same exception occurs. I doubt, there is some problem with the service. But it works fine with Curl, and that is what makes me think there is something wrong in my part

Answer (score 1):

That's not how data is sent in a POST request. It should look like this:

```
string PostData= "name=TestName";
```

If you have more than one value, you separate them with the `&` character. Example:

```
string PostData= "name=TestName&number=20";
```

Comment: But the documentation says it should be sent in the json format. and btw, i had already tried the method u suggested and it also resulted in the same exception

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the documentation in the questiom

Comment: @Sharun: Then it's not really a REST service... Anyway, what's in your `ContentType` variable? Is the response coming with the content type `application/json`?

Comment: ContentType="application/json"

Comment: @Sharun: You have set the `Accept` header to `application/json` also, is that the content type of the response?

Comment: Ya on successful execution, the response should be json data. I am getting the json response using CURL

Comment: @Sharun: Do you have the correct value in the `Method` variable, so that the code that sends the post data is executed?

Comment: The code execute correctly till `using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`

Comment: @Sharun: Have you verified that the code in the `if` statement actually is executed? There is nothing in there that is needed to send the request, it's only needed to send the correct data in the request.

Comment: Ya I checked line by line with the debugger, and checked the content length of request object too, to ensure that the data is there. I think the issue is something else. This code used to work fine for me with normal post, I mean those requests that send data like you said in your answer.

Comment: What confuses me is the Curl call works fine with Json data and C# is failing

Comment: @Sharun: I can't see anything else wrong with the code. I suggest that you try commenting out all settings that are not essential for the request, where the default values would work, for example the accept, keepalive and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the System.Net.Http HttpClient class.

```
        string PostData = @"{""name"":""TestName""}";

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

        var content = new StringContent(PostData, 
            Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), "application/json");

        httpClient.PostAsync("http://something.com:1234/content/abc.v1.json", content);
```

Comment: @Sharun Microsoft support .NET 4 also.  http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/