# asp.net parse json array

Tags: asp.net, json

I write this code for read json in httphandler:

```
var jsonSerilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonString = String.Empty;
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

and my json string is:

```
{"r_id":"140","name":"d","count":"5","c_id":"150"}
```

and i use this method for parse json string:

```
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic a = j.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(object));
            string r_id = a["r_id"];
            string Name = a["name"];
            string count = a["count"];
            string c_id = a["c_id"];
```

up code parse my json string to :
r_id:140 
name:d
count:5
c_id:50

When client send me array of string json for example :

```
{"r_id":"140","name":"d","count":"5","c_id":"150"}
{"r_id":"150","name":"der","count":"50","c_id":"150"}
```

i can parse up json string
How can i?
I use this code:

```
 var jsonSerilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonString = String.Empty;
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", "GetJSON to FROM:"+ jsonString+"\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
            JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic a = j.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<ClientMessage>));
            foreach (var obj in a)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", obj.name + "\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
            }
```

but when program recieve to File.AppendAll.. program crash and down.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you having trouble parsing those JSON strings? If so, what is your issue? You need to be specific in describing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to create a model ( class to hold your objects) like this :

```
Class ClientMessage {
           public string   r_id {get;set;}
          public string name {get;set;}
            public string count {get;set;}
            public string c_id {get;set;}
}
```

In this case you would receive a List , so try to do it like this :

```
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic a = j.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<ClientMessage>));
```

// and then iterate on your object

```
foreach (var obj in a)
{
//start assigning values


}
```

Comment: thanks my friends,but how can i write code in foreach loop for example string name=ob[i].text?

Comment: @wizperr i write obj.name but program is crash!

Comment: i copy and paste your code and customize to my code,and into the foreach loop write a simple str+=obj.name and when client send json,program get a string json but when recieve into foreach loop program goto catch block.

Comment: whats the exception msg ur getting in the catch ?

Comment: catch=System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: "r_id":"25","name":"ka","count":"2","c_id":"150"}.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at Portal.Get_O.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

Comment: Oh i see, please use JSON.stringify when you post ur json from the page

Comment: thanks to pay attention to me my friend,i write code in c# for client and when send the json,json type is string and this json string send :{"r_id":"25","name":"ka","count":"2","c_id":"150"}

Comment: right, but when you post Json it has to come from Javascript, therefore you have to use JSON.stringify, even if you think its string

Comment: i use this tutorial for my client:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-the-server

Comment: I see, in that case, try to formulate your object there and serialize it, according to your tutorial it should look something like this:

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
          
ClientMessage msg=new ClientMessage();
msg.r_id="123";
msg.name="gd";
msg.count="5";
msg.c_id="45";
List<ClientMessage> _list=new List<ClientMessage>();_list.add(msg)
//serialize it
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_list).ToString();

streamWriter.Write(json);
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an object you can parse your JSON into, so something like:

```
public MyClass {

    public int r_id { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

This will allow you to parse directly into that object, like this:

```
var results = j.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: how can i use foreach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something this code, I am assuming you are getting json data like below.

```
[
    {
        r_id: "123",
        name: "deepu",
        count:"5",
        c_id:"150"
    },
    {
        r_id: "444",
        name: "aaa",
        count:"25",
        c_id:"55"
    },
    {
        r_id: "5467",
        name: "dfgdf",
        count:"5",
        c_id:"3434"
    }
]
```

> I am using the above Client Message class here and adding JsonProperty attribute.

```
public class ClientMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("r_id")]
    public string RId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("c_id")]
    public string Cid { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, get the json data fort testing, I am reading the data from external file..

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("jsondata.txt");
var jsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientMessage>>(data);
```

NOTE : You need to add Newtonsoft.Json reference in your project

Comment: How can i parse r_id[2]?

Comment: var jsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientMessage[]>(data);
var rid2 = jsResult[2].RId;