# Posting a dictionary as data to HTTPS server in C# using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, https, python-requests, dotnet-httpclient

I am required to connect to a `HTTPS` server and post data in the form of a `Dictionary` to it. The server API is created by my teacher and he has provided Python code on how to post to the server, using the Python library `Reguests` (see [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp)).

**The Python template using Requests**

```
def call_server(move): //Move is an integer value
   res = requests.post(SERVER_ADRESS,
                       data={
                           "id": ID, 
                           "move": move, 
                           "api_key": API_KEY,
                       })
```

where of course `SERVER_ADRESS`, `ID`, `move` and `API_KEY` all are provided.

I am trying to rewrite this functionality in `C#` using the `HttpClient` class. I have tried using the method `PostAsync` in `HttpClient` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpclient-postasync(system-string-system-net-http-httpcontent))) by using both a `StringConent` and a `FormUrlEncodedContent` object as the `HttpContent` (can be seen below). However both methods results in the server responding with the error code *422 - Unprocessable Entity*. Which apperently means

> The server understands the content type and syntax of the request entity, but still server is unable to process the request for some reason.

**My template using HttpClient**

```
class HttpHandler
{
   static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   static readonly string SERVER_ADRESS = ...
   static readonly string ID = ...
   static readonly string APIKey = ...
   Dictionary<string, string> data;
   
   public void callServer(int move)
   {
      data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      data.Add("id", ID);
      data.Add("move", move.ToString());
      data.Add("api_key", APIKey);
      string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); //From Newtonsoft.Json
      HttpContent stringCont = new StringContent(serialized,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");    
      HttpContent byteCont = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
            
      var resStringCont = client.PostAsync(SERVER_ADDRESS, stringCont);
      //var resByteCont = client.PostAsync(SERVER_ADDRESS, byteCont);
   } 
}
```

Anyone more experienced with Https that can figure out why I can't successfully post to the server?

Comment: Does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468484/how-to-post-json-with-httpclient-using-c

Comment: FWIW unless there is a certificate problem, which it doesn't seem to be, I doubt the issue is related to HTTPS

Comment: Have you checked the json? Does it look ok?

Comment: @PoulBak The Json looks fine!

Comment: Trying to find some documentation on python-requests .post method.... I can only guess that using `data=` will send a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

Comment: Even searching the source code doesn't make that obvious (https://github.com/psf/requests/search?q=application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: In the StringContent case you're JSON-serializing that move property as a string (e.g. `"move": "5"`) rather than a number (e.g. `"move": 5`). It might be worth a try to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` in that case and don't `ToString()` the move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach, it works with the server I am sending data to.

```
var content = new StringContent("{some:json}");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;"));
                
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://SERVER_ADRESS", content);
```

I suspect the request header is the reason, and send `StringContent` instead of `FormUrlEncodedContent`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I managed to solve it by simply running a Python script containing the provided template. Thanks for your efforts though!