# Xamarin Android client post JSON to Node JS web service

Tags: c#, android, node.js, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am having trouble with sending `JSON` data from my Android application written in `C#` using Xamarin Android (`MvvmCross`).

The function in Android application could run with no exception; however, my web service (written in `Node JS` using `Express`) seems not detecting the post request on its endpoint. Note that the other endpoints which use `get` (to send the data from web service to Android app) are working perfectly.

Below is my function to post my data to my web service

```
public async Task<int> insertSales(IEnumerable<Models.SalesTable> newsales)
    {
        /*ServerDatabaseApi.insertSalesEndpoint =  "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + 
        "/insertsales";*/
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(ServerDatabaseApi.insertSalesEndpoint);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newsales, Formatting.Indented);
                streamwriter.Write(json);
                streamwriter.Flush();
            }
            return 1;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When running the function above, it is always succeed (`return 1;` always executes). I have also tried checking the JSON serialization and it is working perfectly fine.

Below also attached the endpoint code used to serve the data.

```
/*endpoint for inserting a new sales to sales table*/
app.post('/insertsales', function(appReq, appRes){
    console.log("Insert sales; count : "+ appReq.body.length);
    sql.connect(conn).then(function(){
        console.log("Insert sales; count : "+ appReq.body.length);
        for (var i = 0 ; i < appReq.body.length ; i++) {
            new sql.Request()
            .query("insert into SalesTable " +
            "values     ('"+appReq.body[i].DocumentNo+"','"+appReq.body[i].DateCreated+"','"+appReq.body[i].Location+"',"+
            appReq.body[i].TotalDiscountAmount+","+appReq.body[i].Total+",'"+appReq.body[i].SalesmanId+"','"+
            appReq.body[i].CustomerId+"',"+appReq.body[i].Latitude+","+appReq.body[i].Longitude+")")
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I tried to trace whether it reached the endpoint or not using `console.log`. However, it never executes.

Could you help me to spot where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your .NET code that actually sends the `WebRequest`. You create the request, write some JSON to it's stream, and flush it. Here's a simple way to make the network call (untested):

```
 public async Task<int> InsertSales(IEnumerable<Models.SalesTable> newSales)
 {
     var ipAddress = "";// your IP address here
     var port = ""; // your port here
     var endpoint = $"http://{ipAddress}:{port}/insertsalesline";
     var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newSales);
     var content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
         var reponse = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content);
         if (reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             return 1;
         else
             return 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you for the help and explanation! Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027534/5023889 answer, at first I thought `.Flush` is already sending the `WebRequest`.