# C# POST sending Request Payload JSON data - login to nike.com

Tags: c#, json, winforms, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying login to nike.com with my C# windows application.

```
     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://unite.nike.com/login?appVersion=376&experienceVersion=318&uxid=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&locale=en_US&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Google%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=true&native=false&visit=1&visitor=048a11da-9ba2-4a4b-91c3-e3cc2774694c");

        string stringData = "appVersion=376&experienceVersion=318&uxid=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&locale=en_US&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Google%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=true&native=false&visit=1&visitor=048a11da-9ba2-4a4b-91c3-e3cc2774694c";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        request.Referer = "https://m.nike.com/us/en_us/?l=shop,login_register";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Headers.Add("origin", "https://m.nike.com");
        request.Headers.Add("cookie", "AnalysisUserId=104.96.91.109.102041520967791940; exp.swoosh.user=%7B%22granted%22%3A0%7D; nike_locale=us/en_us; NIKE_COMMERCE_COUNTRY=US; NIKE_COMMERCE_LANG_LOCALE=en_US; guidU=7d702b13-ba36-4c8a-d743-f726b99d8807; neo.swimlane=52; dreams_sample=44; cicIntercept=1; cicGuestIntercept=1; cto_lwid=a72ef9b0-3206-45ff-91c7-cf41bf80c118; RES_TRACKINGID=303445732649467; ResonanceSegment=1; AMCVS_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1; AKNIKE=CT-2; lls=3; NIKE_COMMERCE_CCR=1520971547200; CONSUMERCHOICE_SESSION=t; CONSUMERCHOICE=us/en_us; bm_sz=BB6980129B3DFBC73F801C679C8953FB~QAAQbVtgaHQolR5iAQAAceRoI+xF8PxoczE2kGatzaDU90mSX4sJNBTWHwhFh7uDbTBpEQHu9AfqzSCrZKBDtteV5n2LhACXIuzQPezvcsAV4beXFH8tNbnpCs2PEvR7OU9em9lBpGFcKorAL8+S5xz0pTfCxfFlBuI/jXzeXOToMSbg4sbv9Z8Cktgy; guidS=eb252880-ba16-468d-f497-070593e9031c; RES_SESSIONID=718716042916119; AMCV_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=2121618341%7CMCIDTS%7C17604%7CMCMID%7C50402020119854507093682697974758826217%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1521019750s%7CNONE; ak_bmsc=A51447336BE456E9AF9F08FFF8188EAA68605B6DDC27000013CFA85AEF1E1F19~plBWC7o30uP95yZXaGw7lBKJ4dm6/EyPeO9FAJdZdKsRmLIsW/rBraVYu2IUQMMTzazdq8S4a9PTCJGxaaNGIXxedF/Z1NA1A/EdQFeCCKL9nnFtlavdjlwi2eFiKcBQhJ+bcS8k0tuQKJ1cNS2ng6Me92rK7RrBqtg85tNGZytGfTHxJUd7jWWF43tskP9lnsbmau+myiG1dhgpLSG+40zS02iXa3U0uSZv6gLlNxssDgQEJC/orrdIs/XKOxdsHXuqVzq3RsYGyWzaz05xqUrQ==; neo.experiments=%7B%22main%22%3A%7B%223039-interceptor%22%3A%22a%22%2C%223250-interceptor%22%3A%22a%22%7D%2C%22plus%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mobile%22%3A%7B%223199-interceptor%22%3A%22a%22%2C%223246-interceptor%22%3A%22a%22%7D%7D; USID=8049283F7E6AF657B21C7DEB135F66F6.sin-239-app-us-0; _abck=71900787CAC90E301D55611832D59B6268605B6DDC2700000720A85A5D67BF01~0~gnbkwgPHLhkJw9twiqxqN8vDHgFrBO4hdMKVy2uNJLY=~-1~-1; s_sess=%20c51%3Dvertical%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20tp%3D5325%3B%20s_ppv%3Dnikecom%25253Ehomepage%252C12%252C12%252C640%3B%20prevList2%3D%3B; slCheck=N; llCheck=N; sls=0; utag_main=_st:1521016412752$ses_id:1521012619059%3Bexp-session; s_pers=%20c58%3Dno%2520value%7C1521016402289%3B%20s_dfa%3Dnikecomprod%7C1521016414639%3B; guidSTimestamp=1521012520794|1521014615096; bm_sv=86FAB72505FE57713A77C0CA3407044F~o/nQM0bVBprEbVN+2VGk4ea4sVZcujD42BoLvCRxpu5NKwgMTO3oYvgHyrOfOp6h8hv1tI0+3tH/0i3tM3eX8PCQLcibu6uf3iTtPDKnHFTtfDkN+8R4UN0nD0p7L9RGwrkRLuzauSMSonmJHxzCD1HCzVft9Pjx0r02SuViioM=; ppd=profile%7Cnikecom%3Eprofile%3Elogin%20start; _uetsid=_uetef349e8d; bc_nike_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2216220f6b312234-0cca71d41deec1-b353461-1fa400-16220f6b3134a6%22%7D");
        request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en,hr;q=0.9");
        request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.Add("authority", "unite.nike.com");
        request.Headers.Add("path", "/login?appVersion=376&experienceVersion=318&uxid=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&locale=en_US&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Google%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=true&native=false&visit=1&visitor=048a11da-9ba2-4a4b-91c3-e3cc2774694c");
        request.Headers.Add("scheme", "https");
        var newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        //MessageBox.Show((((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode.ToString()));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

I don't know how to include Request Payload data in my request
[image]

With current code I receive response from server:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

How to include JSON data in my POST request?

Comment: You didn't just post your _actual_ username and password hash, did you?

Comment: Also, if you get 401 there is something wrong with your login, probably not so much your payload.

Comment: @Fildor no that was not my actual  login data, I used it as a test. I receive 401 because of missing login data which I need to send in JSON format. Please take back my photo. Thanks.

Comment: There you go. So the login data *is* the content you are trying to send, do I get that correctly?

Comment: Yes, I want to send password and username, goal is to login on website,  I don't know how to include it in my request since it's JSON format.

Comment: A little search brought this up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10027534/982149 , hope it helps. (I am assuming the problem is _how_ to send json, not _what to send_ ...)

Comment: The first two subsections here could also help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/support-for-json-and-other-data-transfer-formats