# Xamarin/C# POST to RESTful api

Tags: c#, xamarin, opayo

Apologies if this is a stupid question, i've been thrown onto a project with very little prior C#/Xamarin knowledge and I've been banging my head against a wall with this for some time.

So...

I'm trying to make a post call to SagePay API 
(https://test.sagepay.com/documentation/#card-identifiers)

I've been accessing our API and i've accessed the other SagePay API fine,

what i'm having issues with is that this call is a 'nested' json (apologies for incorrect terminology)

How do I go about submitting a POST in this format

```
{
"cardDetails":
    {
        "cardholderName": "SAM JONES",
        "cardNumber": "4929000000006",
        "expiryDate": "0320",
        "securityCode": "123"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is no different than less-nested json. What is your code?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Take a look this link [How to post JSON to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-the-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your objects created in that link (json2csharp):

```
public class CardDetails
{
    public string cardholderName { get; set; }
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    public string expiryDate { get; set; }
    public string securityCode { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize (JSON.Net):

```
var cardIdentifier = new RootObject{
    cardDetails = new CardDetails{
        cardholderName = "EdSF", 
        cardNumber = "4111111111111111", 
        expiryDate = "0320", 
        securityCode = "123"
    }
};


Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cardIdentifier));
```

Result:

```
{
  "cardDetails": {
    "cardholderName": "EdSF",
    "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
    "expiryDate": "0320",
    "securityCode": "123"
  }
}
```

Hth....

Answer (score 0):

you basically represent the JSON as an object and wrap it

```
public class CardDetails
{
    public string cardholderName { get; set; }
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    public string expiryDate { get; set; }
    public string securityCode { get; set; }
}

public class YourObject
{
    public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
}
```