# How to send data in a POST request with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

In my post request I need to send data as follows:

```
{
   "LoginData":{
      "name": "xyz",
      "password": "pw"
   }
}
```

I have not seen an example of such a header (two levels json)

Comment: what do you mean? Convert your json string to a byte[] and send it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post JSON to a server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` to achieve this. where you have to create C# class of your json format, you can do it from [here](http://json2csharp.com/). and then serialize your c# object using `newtonsoft.json` and then use `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient`.