# how to post array json .net?

Tags: c#, json

i am inserting json format but need to know how i can insert in this format as mention below

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": "55",
            "name": "testing data",
            "price": "77",
            "total": "77",
            "quantity": "1",
            "type": "kg"
        }],


 ],
    "totals": [
        {
            "code": "sub_total",
            "title": "Sub-Total",
            "text": "Rs277.00",
            "value": "277.0000",
            "sort_order": "1"
        }]
    }
```

here is my code which i am trying

```
items local = new items();
foreach (var item in _LocalItem){

    local = new items
    {
        name = item.name
    };
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(local);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://orangepotato.rjcpacking.com/index.php?route=api/login/addcustomerOrder");
request.Content = new StringContent(json);
```

i dont understand where i can add "products" array in json format

Comment: that `foreach` look looks very suspicious... it is discarding whatever you put into `local`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post JSON to a server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

Simply: don't serialize an array - serialize something that *has* an array in a member called `products`:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { products = local });
```

Comment: cool, i have edit my question what about if i have json data like this check my question please.