# How do we create JSON object [FromBody] and postasync to another api from existing webapi?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Lets say I have Employee object coming from client via Post and we receive it in Webapi via [FromBody] attribute.

May I know, how to transfer this object by converting to Json again and posting it to another webapi? The response from this will be integer value. Which I will sending back to the client.

Also, I am trying to make this as Asynchronous.

I tried searching various sites and posts for hours and could not reach to a solution.

Appreciate your help :) Thanks.

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<ActionResult<int>> GetValue([FromBody] Employee emp)
{
}
```

Comment: _"May I know, how to transfer this object by converting to Json again and posting it to another webapi?"_ - have you done any research on this? Sending an object via JSON is an incredibly common task, so there are many existing questions on this site doing exactly this.

Comment: Yes John I did my research, I understand, back in the days I even tried using DataContractJsonSerializer in WCF and it used to work fine. I tried few things but those assemblies are not compatible in Web Api project. I am clueless.

I tried something like this,
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var jsonserializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
              JsonNetFormatter won't resolve -- >  //var jsonFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(jsonserializerSettings.Add());

Comment: The first Google result for the query _"how to post JSON to a server in C#"_ yields [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c), from which I reckon [this is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266816/3181933). Note the section comment about using HttpClientFactory instead of `using (var client = new HttpClient())` everywhere.

Comment: No John, perhaps you are right, I am looking for using client.PostAsync method example. I will be using the Task<ActionResult<int>> here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to convert object into json.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);
```

Then you call your external web api using [httpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) or use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url");
    var result = await client.PostAsync("/endpoint", jsonString);

    // use below as you want
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Mate, that's not correct, jsonstring is not HttpContent, in PostAsync, Httpcontent object is expected as second parameter.

Comment: @OptimusPrime kindly mention the correct way.