# How to send complex data to controller endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this basic case:

```cs
    [HttpPost("endpoint")]
    public IActionResult Endpoint(DateTime date, string value, bool modifier)
    {
        return Ok($"{date}-{value}-{modifier}");
    }
```

and I'm able to send a request to it with

```cs
    var testContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "date", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() },
        { "value", "value1" },
        { "modifier", true.ToString() }
    });
```

Instead I want my endpoint to be this instead

```cs
    [HttpPost("endpointwithlist")]
    public IActionResult EndpointWithList(DateTime date, List<string> value, bool modifier)
    {
        return Ok($"{date}-{value.FirstOrDefault()}-{modifier}");
    }
```

How do I send this? I have tried the below, nothing works

```cs
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { date, value = valueCollection.ToArray(), modifier });
    var testContentWithList = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    testContentWithList.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might create a model class for the payload

```
public class EndpointWithListModel
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public List<string> Value {get; set;}
    public bool Modifier {get; set;}
}
```

the method parameter then could use `[FromBody]` attribute

```
public IActionResult EndpointWithList([FromBody]EndpointWithListModel model)
```

then send the json to your POST method, example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c). Using `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
    "http://yourUrl", 
     new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Comment: This worked. I had actually tried this, but I was missing the [FromBody] attribute.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work if I can't change the endpoint?

Comment: [FromBody] can be used also on simple parameters (strings, ints..), I do not know if it is possible to use multiple FromBody attributes in one method, probably not possible, there is only one body in the request.

Comment: You're correct, from the microsoft docs, it shouldn't be passed to more than one parameter per method. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

if your variables(date, valueController and modifier) are in the right type, following code should work.

```
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { date:date, value : valueCollection.ToArray(), modifier:modifier });
```

Comment: The question is how then do I send that json string to the controller?

Comment: you said 'How do I send this? I have tried the below, nothing works' . I meant you should fix that code which is not working with the one i write above.