# Send post data to api in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this api in php that works ok when sending data from an html form.

```
<?php

include_once 'apiAppMovil.php';

$api = new AppMovil();
$error = '';

if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["ape"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])){

    if($api->subirImagen($_FILES['foto'])){
        $item = array(
            "nombre" => $_POST["nombre"],
            "ape" => $_POST["ape"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "pass" => $_POST["pass"],
            "foto" => $api->getImagen() //Not used
        );
        
        $api->add($item);
    }else{
        $api->error('Error con el archivo: ' . $api->getError());
    }
}
else{
    $api->error('Error al llamar a la API');
}
```

?>

I want to send data but from c#. My class is the following:

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{/*
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Id { get; set; }*/

    [JsonProperty("nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ape")]
    public string Ape { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pass")]
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("foto")] //Not Used
    public string Foto { get; set; }
}
```

and my method is:

```
private async Task SignUpApiPost()
    {
        var data = new Item
        {
            Nombre = "Eric",
            Ape = "Pino",
            Pass = "M2022",
            Email = "ericpinodiaz@gmail.com",
            Foto = "default.jpeg" //Not Used
        };

        // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
        var httpContent = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // Do the actual request and await the response
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://app.domainexample.com/rest/add.php", httpContent);
                    
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
             //do thing             
        }
    }
```

But I can't get the data to arrive, I have the errors **"Error al llamar a la API"** from Api php.
I think the problem is that ***var data = new Item{*** is not declared correctly, can you help me and tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Edit:

I add the html with which it works correctly:

[image]

Comment: Use a sniffer and compare the working php request with the c# request.  Make c# request look exactly like working php.  The default http headers in c# are different from php.  Usually getting modifying the c# header solve issue.

Comment: You are passing foto property as a string, not as a file. Can you remove $_FILES from "foto" in php code and change it same as other properties and check?

Comment: I have eliminated $_FILES["photo"] to rule out a possible problem but it is still the same, it returns a Null at the end

Comment: I edit my question and add the html with which it works correctly.

Comment: The header that specifies the content type of your http content is `string[]` (the default), which causes PHP to try and interpret the body as a string array.

try setting the request content type to `text/json`. see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c

dotnetfiddle that shows what i am talking about : 

https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIZhMG

Comment: And how can I solve it? what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like the one below.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("your url");

//HTTP POST
var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<StudentViewModel>("your  parameter name",    Item);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this code, it returns StatusCode 200, but I do not create the record in my table: var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Item>(client.BaseAddress, data);

Comment: that is problem with the api then check your api

Comment: my api save record in table like this: function nuevoUsuario($usuario){
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre) VALUES (:nombre)');
        $query->execute(['nombre' => $usuario['nombre']                  
                     );
        return $query;
    } I have modified the API so that it only adds the NAME

Comment: Sorry, I am not a PHP guy so don't know much about it. But check your models and see if you are getting your models correctly.